# My dropdown list which is working fine in create view. but in edit view this dropdown did not load object original values

Tags: c#, dropdown, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

This is my dropdown list which is working fine in create view. but in edit view this dropdown did not load object original values

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FundingSource, new List<SelectListItem>
                {new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP", Value = "ADP"},
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "CG", Value = "CG"},
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP(D)", Value = ADP(D)"},                   
                 new SelectListItem {Text = "Others", Value = "Others"}                         
               }, --Select--,new {@class="form-control"})
```

Comment: You missed a double quotation in third item of SelectList. new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP(D)", Value = ADP(D)"}. It should be new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP(D)", Value = "ADP(D)"}. And --Select-- should be a string. "--Select--". But your code works when these bugs are fixed. By the way what do you mean 'object original values'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. Be aware that you should fill your model in your action before loading the View.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FundingSource, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
            {new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP", Value = "ADP"},
             new SelectListItem {Text = "CG", Value = "CG"},
             new SelectListItem {Text = "ADP(D)", Value = "ADP(D)"},
             new SelectListItem {Text = "Others", Value = "Others"}
           }, "Text", "Value", Model.FundingSource), "--Select--",new {@class="form-control"})
```